# Looking for a way to retrieve date in velocity template

Tags: java, templates, velocity

I'm trying to get the System date in a velocity template, but 
    ModifiedDateTime="$date"
results in 
    ModifiedDateTime="$date" instead of ModifiedDateTime="Jan 11, 2011 9:54:50 AM"

All of my other variables and calls work as supposed to, but this is my first Velocity template and everything I can find points at $date.

Answer (score 8):

I think you need to provide `$date` variable like [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Velocity/HowtouseDateinVelocity.htm)

Comment: If it's not in the VelocityContext then you can access it so as @Nikita says you'll need to add it

Comment: Also worth checking out the [DateTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html) for formatting dates

Answer (score 3):

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/releases/2.0/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html

is very helpful for such things...

Answer (score 0):

So velocity tools were packaged...had to use $tools.date,